# Insert values from a record variable into a table

Tags: postgresql, insert, plpgsql, functions, record

I am developing a user-defined function that takes two arguments:

```
create or replace function gesio(
    events_table_in regclass,  
    events_table_out regclass)
returns void as $$ ... $$
```

`events_table_in` and `events_table_out` have exactly the same schema.

Simply explained, I loop through the records of `events_table_in`, manipulate the records and want to append (insert) the manipulated records into `events_table_out` in the following fashion:

```
OPEN recCurs FOR execute 
format('SELECT * FROM %s order by session_id, event_time', event_table_in);

LOOP
    FETCH recCurs into rec;
    if not found then
      exit;
    end if;

    -- 1. do something with rec

    -- 2. insert the rec into events_table_out

end loop;
```

How can I save the `rec` into `events_table_out`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There **is** a solution with just PL/pgSQL. Simple and elegant, too. Pretty advanced stuff, though.
Requires Postgres **9.0** or later (workaround for older versions possible).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gesio(_tbl_in anyelement, _tbl_out regclass)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   FOR _tbl_in IN EXECUTE
      format('SELECT * FROM %s', pg_typeof(_tbl_in))
   LOOP
      -- do something with record

      EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %s SELECT $1.*', _tbl_out)
      USING _tbl_in;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Call (important!):

```
SELECT gesio(NULL::t, 't1');
```

`t` and `t1` being tables with identical schema.

The polymorphic parameter (`anyelement`) is only needed if you need it's value or data type for the computation in the function body. Else you can simplify like demonstrated in this later answer:

- [Insert values from a record variable into a subclass table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163962/insert-values-from-a-record-variable-into-a-subclass-table/164224#164224)

#### Major ingredients

- [Implicit cursor of a `FOR` loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) instead of explicit cursor. That's generally preferable.
- [Polymorphic types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC)
- [Object identifier types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html)
- [Dynamic SQL in plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)
- [`VALUES` can take a row type directly.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23249595/939860)

An obstacle to overcome is that variables inside the function cannot be defined as polymorphic type `anyelement` (yet). [This related answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7635605/939860) explains the solution. Provides a **workaround for older versions**, too.

I am handing in a `NULL` value of type `t`, which serves three purposes:

- Provide table name.
- Provide table type.
- Serve as loop variable.

The *value* of the first parameter is discarded. Just use `NULL`.

Consider [this related answer on SO with more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751557/939860). The most interesting part being the last chapter *"Various complete table types"*.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=337f53ceab6e655b370c6b0a5337d198)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4f363/1)</sub>

If your computations are not too sophisticated, you may be able to replace the loop with a single dynamic SQL statement, which is typically faster.

Comment: +1... I haven't thought in `anyelement` for that. Seems a pretty simple and good solution.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately it is not easy to parse the `RECORD` type using PL/pgSQL. If the structure of the tables passed in arguments are always the same as some other table or type you could use this type directly instead of `RECORD`, and then use the following:

```
DECLARE
    recCurs table_or_type;
...
BEGIN
...
OPEN recCurs FOR EXECUTE ...
...
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || events_table_out || ' VALUES(($1).*)'
        USING recCurs;
...
```

But this will not work with `RECORD` type. The only solution I can think of is creating the query by hand. But PL/pgSQL gives no way to dynamically get the keys of an `RECORD` type. So you have to use some external tools. The best (in my opinion) for this kind of job is the [`hstore` extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html). Once installed you can create it on your database (the following works only on 9.1+, for earlier you should do it by hand):

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
```

Now. You are able to convert a `RECORD` type to an `hstore` type, using `hstore(recCurs)`, and so you can dynamically iterate over its keys and values with the `each` function:

```
DECLARE
   recCurs record;
   kv record;
   v_cols text;
   v_vals text;
BEGIN
...
    OPEN recCurs FOR EXECUTE ...
...
    -- 1. do something with rec

    -- 2. insert the rec into events_table_out:
    v_cols := '';
    v_vals := '';
    FOR kv IN SELECT * FROM each(hstore(recCurs)) LOOP
        v_cols := v_cols || kv.key || ',';
        v_vals := v_vals || quote_nullable(kv.value) || ',';
    END LOOP;
    v_cols := substr(v_cols, 1, length(v_cols)-1);
    v_vals := substr(v_vals, 1, length(v_vals)-1);
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || events_table_out
            || '(' || v_cols || ') '
            || 'VALUES (' || v_vals || ')';
...
```

Of course, it will only work if the table "pointed" by `events_table_out` has all the columns that `events_table_in` has (the first can have more columns).

**RESUMING:** always you want some dynamic key/value data-type on PL/pgSQL, and `RECORD` is not enough, the `hstore` can be used.

Comment: `hstore` is generally good advice and your answer is pretty useful (+1). It just so happens that there is a simpler solution for the case.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, your answer is (with no doubt) really better, simpler and probably more performatic. I'll keep my answer here, because it does solve the problem, not the best way though.

Comment: The `quote_literal` in `v_vals := v_vals || quote_literal(kv.value) || ',';` inside the LOOP should be `quote_nullable`, otherwise the whole EXECUTE become NULL in case of NULL values in the record.

Comment: @gabrimonfa, you are correct. fixed

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similar and ended up using the INSERT from SELECT. I need to duplicate records in the same table but changing one field. Maybe it's not the most ellegant solution but it works.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.duplicar_mascotas(
    origen integer DEFAULT 0, 
    destino integer DEFAULT 0
)
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
  fila_mascota record;
  nvo_id_mascota BIGINT;
  contador integer;
  cur_mascotas cursor for
    SELECT id FROM public.mascotas WHERE id_persona = origen;
BEGIN
    contador := 0;
    raise notice 'hola';
    open cur_mascotas;
    loop
        fetch cur_mascotas into fila_mascota;
        exit when not found;
        -- insert del select
        INSERT INTO public.mascotas ( nombre, id_persona, edad_meses) 
        SELECT nombre, destino as id_persona, edad_meses
        FROM public.mascotas
        WHERE 
            id = fila_mascota.id;
        contador := contador + 1;
    end loop;
    return contador;
END;
$function$
```

Then, i call the function like so:

```
select duplicar_mascotas (1,2);
```

This duplicates the records from the person with id = 1 to the person with id = 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the sql commands below:

```
/* variant 1 */
insert into test_history select v_history_row.*;
/* variant 2 */
execute 'insert into test_history SELECT $1.*' using v_history_row;
```

Comment: For future visitors, please dpread it out and explain it.