# Automatic conversion of anonymous records returned from an UDF to well known table-type

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, type-conversion, functions, composite-types

Proprietary code (that we cannot change) has a bunch of user defined functions of the type:

```
create or replace function f() returns record as $$ ... $$
```

which we call in the following way (for example):

```
SELECT status, log FROM f() as (status boolean, log text);
```

`(status boolean, log text)` is a rowtype of table `T`. Is it possible to automatically convert the `record` (or `setof record` return type) into the `T` rowtype without listing the attributes? What I am looking for is of the kind:

```
SELECT * FROM f() as T%rowtype
```

Comment: If the function does not have arguments, you could wrap that into a view.

Comment: Or you could just as well wrap these into functions in an other schema but an identical signature.  Or if you know the source, create your own, usable set of them.

Comment: Technically, I think, what you suggest is not possible.

Comment: @dezso: I found a way for functions returning a single row.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes, and it is as simple as it can be, but still a wrapping :). Assignment to and from record/row variables are full of surprises by the way.

Comment: @dezso: Yeah, there are a couple of obstacles in the handling records where improvements would be quite welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a way.

Given a table `t` and a function `f()` that returns an anonymous record that would match that table type:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id int, d date);
```

You cannot just cast the anonymous record, since a column definition list is *required* for

```
SELECT * FROM f()
```

Quoting [the manual on the SELECT command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM):

> If the function has been defined as returning the record data type,
> then an alias or the key word `AS` must be present, **followed by a column
> definition list** in the form ...

**Bold** emphasis mine.

So, while all of these queries work:

```
SELECT '(1,2013-11-11)'::t;
SELECT ('(1,2013-11-11)'::t).*;
SELECT f();                      -- returning anonymous record
SELECT * FROM f() AS f(id int, d date);
```

Neither of these do:

```
SELECT * FROM f();
SELECT * FROM f()::t;
```

The latter raising an exception:

> ERROR:  cannot cast type record to t

You could wrap the `SELECT` with column definition list into a `VIEW` or function like [@a_horse](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52835/automatic-conversion-of-record-return-type-of-a-udf-into-a-table-row-type-in-pos#comment93591_52835) and [@deszo](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52835/automatic-conversion-of-record-return-type-of-a-udf-into-a-table-row-type-in-pos#comment93667_52835) suggested. That would work just fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v1 AS
SELECT * FROM f() AS f(id int, d date);
```

But that wouldn't answer your question:

> convert the record (or setof record return type) into the `T` rowtype
> without listing the attributes?

#### Solution for single row

While a cast fails, an **assignment in plpgsql** works.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function f1(OUT rec t)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   rec := f();   -- assignment succeeds where cast failed (!)
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f1();
```

While you can also write a set returning function with that pattern I did not find a way to *`SELECT`* from a set returning function without supplying a column definition list ...

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2efbcba29bcfdd6feeb8435f292ce57a)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6f39c/8)</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Your solution to "cast" the signature of the UDF so it returs a table (row) type instead of the record type works. In addition I must say that I successfully used this approach to return a set of records too. In your answer one must replace the line `CREATE OR REPLACE function f1(OUT rec t) AS table type` with `CREATE OR REPLACE function f1() returns setof T as...`.

Comment: The posted question is a simplification of the original problem that I indeed have. My original problem is that the function takes one parameter of type `regclass` as input and returns a `setof` records (the row type of the corresponding input regclass). In this case I cannot create a wrapper function since the return type is known only at the execution time, can't I?

Comment: @arthur: That's tricky stuff. I suggest you create a **new question** with all the necessary details. You can always reference this one for context. I think I have a solution for that ...

Comment: @arthur: I would also be *very* interested in how you managed to SELECT from a set returning function without supplying a column definition list. Can you post an answer with a code example here?

Comment: I do not have an answer how one can do a select query for a function returning `setof record`. I was thinking of possible workarounds and created [inserting-values-from-a-record-variable-into-a-table ticket](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52826/postgres-inserting-values-from-a-record-variable-into-a-table). selecting a function returning `setof T` is relatively straight forward. But I assume that your expression `set retuning function` indeed means `setof record returning function`...

Comment: @ erwin-brandstetter:I posted the answer below for the `setof T` returning function. As I mentioned it is straight forward and I suggest to delete the answer once you confirm the triviality of the solution

Comment: @arthur: Yes, in the context of this question "set returning function" was meant to be a function returning `SETOF record`. I don't know of a way to `SELECT` from that without column definition list.

Comment: A solid answer, here. For me, casting the record to text (or in my case: `format()`ting it as a `%L` literal) did the trick just fine.