# Insert values from a record variable into a subclass table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, parameter

My goal is to create a stored procedure that builds up a `_tbl_out` which is a subclass of a `_tbl_in`. I'm following the results of [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52826/insert-values-from-a-record-variable-into-a-table), but for this to work, the tables need to have the SAME schema. I want the output_table to have the same schema PLUS some extra computed columns.

Will I have to use a less elegant solution than the one linked? Or is there a solution where I can append columns onto the `_tbl_in` record before I insert it to the subclass `_tbl_out`?

Here is the code for the previous solution for reference:

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gesio(_tbl_in anyelement, _tbl_out regclass)
>   RETURNS void AS
> $func$
> BEGIN
>
> FOR _tbl_in IN EXECUTE
>    format('SELECT * FROM %s', pg_typeof(_tbl_in))
> LOOP
>    -- do something with record
>
>    EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %s SELECT $1.*', _tbl_out)
>    USING _tbl_in;
> END LOOP;
>
> END
> $func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
> ```
>
> Call (important!):
>
> ```
> SELECT gesio(NULL::t, 't1');
> ```
>
> `t` and `t1` being the tables with identical schema.

Comment: Do you even need dynamic SQL? Nothing in your question indicates that you have varying tables as source or target. Is that so? Also, the quoted text from my answer does not exactly fit your question `t and t1 being the tables with identical schema.` The point here seems to be that the schema is *not* identical. You should format the quote properly or remove it ...

Comment: Yes, I need dynamic SQL - I was extending the code from the solution in the linked question. I mentioned that _tbl_out is a **subclass** of _tbl_in, so I want _tbl_out to have all the same attributes of _tbl_in plus some extra ones that I will compute. The `t and t1 being the tables with identical schema` refer to **non extended** code, sorry if that was unclear. Fortunately, it turns out extending your code was very simple if I was sure of the order of the attributes (answered below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goal is ...

> a stored procedure that builds up a `_tbl_out` which is a subclass of a `_tbl_in`.

And by "subclass" you mean there are *additional columns at the end of `_tbl_out`*.

So the function shall take two table names and copy contents from the first to the second - plus one or more additional (computed?) columns. The only thing we *know* about table definitions: the second has additional dangling columns.

You only need a polymorphic parameter (`ANYELEMENT`) to pass in or return *values* of dynamic *type* - or at least work with a variable of the type in the function body. What you demonstrate does not return anything (`RETURNS void`) and also has no need for the input *value* or *type*. You only use the table name derived from the input parameter and the parameter itself as auxiliary variable - which goes away after simplifying the function.

Unless you have computations depending on the type or value of the polymorphic parameter, two `regclass` parameters and a single dynamic statement can do the job, and much faster, too. (Or even just two `text` parameters passing valid table names, but `regclass` is more reliable):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.gesio(_tbl_in regclass, _tbl_out regclass)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format($$
      INSERT INTO %s       -- *no* target column list
      SELECT *
           , 'some value'  -- AS computed_column1  -- column alias only for documentation
          -- more ?
      FROM   %s$$$         -- ORDER BY ???
    , _tbl_out, _tbl_in);
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I added a note to my old answer you referenced that was not clear enough:

- [Insert values from a record variable into a table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52826/insert-values-from-a-record-variable-into-a-table/52904#52904)

#### Performance with big tables

A major factor for the resulting cost is the Write Ahead Log (WAL) that has to be maintained for this form. There are ways to avoid that completely and make it substantially faster: Write to a completely new table within the transaction, so it's invisible to the rest of the world until committed. Details:

- [What causes large INSERT to slow down and disk usage to explode?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114856/what-causes-large-insert-to-slow-down-and-disk-usage-to-explode/114926#114926)

Aside: It's a *function*, not a *stored procedure*. Postgres does not have stored procedures, strictly speaking. (The most notable difference: functions always run inside a single transaction scope.)

Comment: Hey Edwin, this is actually very similar to the solution that I came up with. Although simple, I actually found it to be very slow. (_tbl_in is ~1M rows) I think it has something to do with IO because the engine needs to keep creating space for the new rows it's getting from _tbl_in and inserting into _tbl_out. Is this the right intuition for why the function runs so slowly? Do you think it would be faster to create a materialized view to solve this problem?

Comment: @CoreyCole: I guess, this Edwin guy just had the same idea :) Performance: a materialized view wouldn't be a game changer. But there are other ways. I added a chapter with hints. (Plus, there may be other problems hidden in your undisclosed computations.)

Answer (score 0):

I've realized my problem has a very simple solution. As long as we are sure about order of the schema and the extra columns are after all the original columns, my problem is simply solved by adding the values to the `SELECT` of the `INSERT INTO`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gesio(_tbl_in anyelement, _tbl_out regclass)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN

FOR _tbl_in IN EXECUTE
   format('SELECT * FROM %s', pg_typeof(_tbl_in))
LOOP
   -- do something with record
   computed_column1 := 'some value';
   EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %s SELECT $1.*, computed_column1', _tbl_out)
   USING _tbl_in;
END LOOP;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call (important!):

```
SELECT gesio(NULL::t, 't1');
```

t and t1 are tables with identical schemas, but t1 has added a varchar column. The name of the column doesn't matter here because we're only using the order of the columns as they appear in the schemas of the two tables.